# Nothing is working in Earth Engine Code Editor

Tags: google-earth-engine

I created a new project in Google cloud platform and I registered in Google Earth Engine and then I input this into in the code editor:

```
var image = ee.Image('USGS/SRTMGL1_003');
print ('hello world');
```

I also uploaded the following example:

```
var dataset = ee.Image('JRC/GSW1_4/GlobalSurfaceWater');

var visualization = {
  bands: ['occurrence'],
  min: 0.0,
  max: 100.0,
  palette: ['ffffff', 'ffbbbb', '0000ff']
};

Map.setCenter(59.414, 45.182, 6);

Map.addLayer(dataset, visualization, 'Occurrence');
```

However `print`, `ee.Image` or `ee.ImageCollection`, `Map.setCenter`, `Map.addLayer` are appearing in black and not working. I can execute what is imported but I cannot edit it. [image][image: ][1]]

Comment: You should refresh the page and try again. It's very unlikely that it's a problem with the code editor itself.